# using netcat stty not giving complete tty shell when doing CLTR+Z

Tags: linux, bash, tty, netcat

I'm using netcat and stty to get terminal (tty) access, but I'm not able to do so as the CLTR+Z action on the netcat session is giving me `suspended session` instead of `stopped` and then I'm not able to resume the suspended session.

[image]

However, what I expect the output to show as `stopped` as shown here

[image]

Also in the first pic you can see as I try to enter "fg" for the second time I get `^M` plus its says `continued sudo` I'm not sure what wrong I'm doing as I'm just following the guide mentioned here.

https://blog.ropnop.com/upgrading-simple-shells-to-fully-interactive-ttys/

Comment: the first `fg` already got the suspended session back, that was why you saw `continued sudo nc -nlvp 8888`. The `^M` was the enter key pressed after the second `fg`.
I assume the difference between suspended and stopped was just from different shells' terms. Should be not actual differences in this case.

Comment: Thanks @HansChen for input, but the effect I want is to be able to resume the stopped session which is continued in my case. Should I change the shell from zsh to bash and try?